# How can we reduce the size of HOG descriptor changing the size of cells and bloks

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, descriptor

I have a question about reducing the size of HOG descriptor i would like without using methods such as PCA .. to reduce the size of this descriptor and obtain a 16 elements in this vector using a specific number of cells and blocks. Idf you have any idea i will be thankfull.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I test all of the options in HOG, just 'CellSize' reduce the length of descriptor but it does not produce 16 elements.

Comment: If i take an image 128*128 with one cell and one block , and 8 bins i can obtain 16 elements but that traitement don't reduce the robustness of the descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

By using the extractHOGfeatures method given by matlab we can specify the number of blocks and cells so automatically the size of the characteristic vector will be changed